# How to add Edit, update and Cancel buttons actions for programatically created gridview using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I'm, trying to add a grid view to my web page programatically (using VB.net in Visual Studio 2012). im successful in creating a gridview and also added Edit, update and Cancel buttons to my grid. but im struck with adding event commands to these buttons. how to make this buttons work? right know button (edit/Update/Delete) action is not doing anything. below is the code... kindly help. Please help me with the code for Edit, Update and Cancel buttons for gridview (**Programatically added Grid view**).

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click       
   Dim Gv As GridView = New GridView()
   Dim cf As CommandField = New CommandField()
    Dim df As CommandField = New CommandField()
    Dim ef As CommandField = New CommandField()
    cf.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button
    df.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button
    df.ShowCancelButton = True
    cf.ShowEditButton = True
    ef.ShowDeleteButton = True
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT * FROM Table1")
    Gv.Columns.Add(df)  
    Gv.Columns.Add(cf)
    Gv.Columns.Add(ef)
    Gv.DataSource = dt
    Gv.EditIndex = True
    Gv.DataBind()
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(Gv)

    Private Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                sda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler dynamically by using the AddHandler Statement like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click       
    Dim Gv As GridView = New GridView()
    ' ...
    AddHandler Gv.RowUpdated, AddressOf Gv_RowUpdated
    ' ...
End Sub

Protected Sub Gv_RowUpdated(Sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdatedEventArgs)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, adding controls and event handlers dynamically in ASP.NET is very complicated (see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3d01ft1(v=vs.140).aspx) for details). For instance, you'd have to add the event handlers again on each PostBack.

So you might be better off with a solution that just toggles the Visibility of a GridView that you place on the WebForm at design time. If you need to add several GridViews, you might consider using a Repeater control that contains a GridView in each row.